# Reading in directory's in combobox (months) and in the right order

Tags: java, list

I am reading folders from a directory with readallfiles(allow only directory).

This works great except that i am reading in January, February, March etc.

And when i try to put these folders in to a combobox it comes out February, January etc...

Because java reads them in alphabetically.

I have tought of one solution and that is to rename "January" to "1 January", "2 February".

Is there any other way to make it add them to the combobox in the right manner?

like "January", "February", "March", "April", "May".

Thanks for the help ; )